# Commuting fraction of $F_n$

Tags: probability, abstract-algebra, combinatorics, asymptotics, semigroups

Suppose $S$ is a finite semigroup. Let's define the commuting fraction $cf(S) := \frac{|\{(a, b) \in S^2| ab = ba\}|}{|S|^2}$. Alternatively, it can be defined as the probability that two independent uniformly distributed random elements of $S$ commute.

Now, suppose, $A$ is a finite set, $|A| = n$, $F_n$ is the semigroup of all functions $A \to A$ under composition. What is the asymptotics of $cf(F_n)$?

What have I attempted so far:

Let's for $g: A \to A$ define $St(g) := \{a \in A| g(a)=a\}$. Then it is not hard to see, that if $St(a) \cup St(b) = A$, then $a$ and $b$ commute. Thus $cf(F_n)$ is greater than probability that $St(a) \cup St(b) = A$. For any given set $B \subset A$, the probability, that $St(a)=B$ and $A \setminus B \subset St(b)$ is equal to $(\frac{1}{n})^{|B|}(\frac{n-1}{n})^{n-|B|}(\frac{1}{n})^{n-|B|} = (\frac{1}{n})^{n}(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{n-|B|}$. That means, that the probability of $St(a) \cup St(b) = A$ is $\sum_{k = 0}^n C_n^k (\frac{1}{n})^n(1 - \frac{1}{n})^{k} = (\frac{1}{n})^n(2 - \frac{1}{n})^n \geq e^{-n\ln(n)}$. Thus $cf(F_n) = \Omega(e^{-n\log(n)})$.

This bound seems to be quite crude and one-sided. However I found neither any better lower bound nor any non-trivial upper bound.

Comment: By considering the violations of commutativity at a single $x\in A$, you can get $\operatorname{cf}(F_n)=O\left(\frac1n\right)$. I suspect that's too crude and too obvious, but if not, let me know if I should post it as an answer.

Comment: In fact, I think that by considering the violation of commutativity at some subset $B\subset A$ with $|B|=k$, you should be able to get $\operatorname{cf}(F_n)=O\left(\frac1{n^k}\right)$ for all $k$. Perhaps that's a bit more interesting?

Comment: This question was also asked on MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/143058/what-is-the-probability-two-random-maps-on-n-symbols-commute